# Small abelian categories and module categories - preservation of injective and projective objects

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, soft-question, abelian-categories

A soft question on small abelian categories:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck%27s_T%C3%B4hoku_paper

Wikipedia: "The article "Sur quelques points d'algèbre homologique" by Alexander Grothendieck, now often referred to as the Tôhoku paper, was published in 1957 in the Tôhoku Mathematical Journal. It has revolutionized the subject of homological algebra, a purely algebraic aspect of algebraic topology. It removed the need to distinguish the cases of modules over a ring and sheaves of abelian groups over a topological space."

In this paper Grothendieck wrote down the axioms of an "Abelian category".

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category#Grothendieck's_axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category#Grothendieck%27s_axioms)

The Freyd-Mitchell full embedding theorem "classifies" small abelian categories.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell%27s_embedding_theorem

"The precise statement is as follows: if A is a small abelian category, then there exists a ring R (with 1, not necessarily commutative) and a full, faithful and exact functor F: A → R-Mod (where the latter denotes the category of all left R-modules). The functor F yields an equivalence between A and a full subcategory of R-Mod in such a way that kernels and cokernels computed in A correspond to the ordinary kernels and cokernels computed in R-Mod. Such an equivalence is necessarily additive. The theorem thus essentially says that the objects of A can be thought of as R-modules, and the morphisms as R-linear maps, with kernels, cokernels, exact sequences and sums of morphisms being determined as in the case of modules."
....

"However, projective and injective objects in A do not necessarily correspond to projective and injective R-modules."

**Question:** Have small abelian categories $A$ with the property that there is functor $F$ as mentioned above, such that $F$ preserves projective and injective objects, been classified? By this I mean

**"Which small abelian categories has such a functor?"**

If a list exit I ask for a reference to where this list is written down.

https://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/gk.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motive_(algebraic_geometry)#Definition_of_pure_motives

Comment: Crossposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4134992/7062